# Does google iot-core support MQTT WILL messages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, google-cloud-iot

I was wondering if google iot core support will messages concept.
I tried to set will message for topic events on the device (`devices\device-id\events`) but had no luck with it...
any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the Last Will and Testament Message, then no it is not supported by Google IOT Core. Quite sad because it is a very useful feature.

https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/requirements#mqtt_bridge

```
The following features are not supported:

MQTT QoS 2

Arbitrary MQTT topics and subscriptions.

Last Will and Testament (LWT)

Retained messages

Persistent sessions
```